# need help with a simple jQuery problem

Tags: jquery, json

i have a textbox. when the user tabs out of it (.change) - i want to run a json query to get a single string and populate a textbox with it.

everything works fine except the fill on the callback. every single demo/bit of code i can find deals strictly with populating a selectlist on the callback. i do not want to do this.

```
$("#CodeID").change(function() {
    var codeID = $("#CodeID").val();               
    var url = '/diagnosisCodes/GetCodeDescription?CodeID=' + codeID;
    $.getJSON(url, null, function(data) {
        $("#txtDescription").val(data);
    });
});
```

that's what i have now. obviously does not work. any ideas?

Comment: When you say textbox, do you mean a textarea element or an input element of with type text?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work"?  Do you get an error message?  Does the server-side URL actually get called?  What does it return? Firebug is your friend here.

Comment: can you post your the HTML for your textbox?

Answer (score 2):

The issue I see looking this over is that the `data` parameter in your success function will be a JSON object.  So, for example, if your ajax call is returning JSON that looks like

```
{description:"Here's my description"}
```

you'll want to change the line that loads the description to

```
$("#txtDescription").val(data.description);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because `data` is a json data (javascript object) you must get the field that you want from the object

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$("#divDescription").val(data);`

Have you tried `$("#divDescription").append(data);` or `$("#divDescription").html(data);` ?

**edit**

After a brief test I found that val or append will both work if it's a textarea and not a div you are adding to. http://jsbin.com/usije5. Val will just wipe any existing data while append will append to existing data.

Answer (score 1):

MVC Controller had started throwing 500s, because i didn't have JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet set.

Jquery Code is good. thanks for the help!